# Should more questions be closed as Too Localized, than Not A Real Question?

Tags: discussion, too-localized, not-a-real-question

I recently found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989101/hi-i-could-really-use-some-help-on-c-factory-pattern).

In case it gets deleted, it's basically a huge wall of text and the author gives us some compiler error and asks how to fix it.

Now, my question is this: Is this Not A Real Question, or is it Too Localized?

I personally see most of these questions closed as not a real question. I however think it fits more into the too localized category. It gives an answerable question(I think), but who wants to dig through the code for some answer that will only benefit the author? This is why I think it's too localized. Am I wrong?

Comment: If all posts like that were closed then the `android` tag activity would drop by half!

Comment: @dave what is it about android development that turns braincells into mush?

Comment: @Will, I think it's more the number of brand new users who 1) have never used Android before and 2) have never used Java before.  It's a great combination.  The number of times people have to ask for a stacktrace...

Comment: @Will, I think all Java development turns braincells into mush :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have, indeed, begun closing these types of questions as "Too Localized."

Reason: The descriptive text of the "too localized" reason fits better.

- **Not a real question:** "It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form."
- **Too localized:** "This question would only be relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet."